# Is there an argument in sudo to ask for password once before aborting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, when you get a password wrong in sudo, it says "Sorry, try again." until you get it wrong 3 times in a row, as seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e9jD.png). Is there a sudo argument or something you can write in a bash script to make it that once you get the password wrong one time, it exits? Instead of 3?

Comment: `man sudoers` and search for `passwd_tries`. Then `man visudo`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by the `man sudo` you cannot set the retries number.